# Is it possible to perform 2 different segues on the click of 1 button?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue

I have one UIButton inside a ViewController, and I want when I click on the button, according to a custom condition, to show 2 different ViewController. Is that even possible to have 2 segues in one UIButton?

I'm trying to add 2 segues; however, whenever I try to add one the other one is automatically removed.

[image: Img showing one button trying to be connected to 2 different Viewcontrollers]

Comment: Ya it can, then you just performSegue using different identifier. You should go try first instead of asking here, it's a simple thing anyway

Comment: Thanks @Lee , But can you show me some code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, go drag segue from your initial view to another view, and give an identifier for that connection. Then just use code below, with different identifier names you declare at first. Like "segueToView1" to first view and "segueToView2" to another. And remember to use `if else` to know which view you are going

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "identifierName", sender: self)
```

[image: Img showing how to change the segue identifier in a storyboard.]

Comment: Where I put this code exactly?

Comment: what had you completed so far? == Since you want to go to other view when button pressed, then put it inside your IBAction when button click

Comment: Error : terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (app.ViewController: 0x147a67e10>) has no segue with identifier 'firstIdentifier''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182f69900 0x1825d7f80 0x187fcfdb4 0x10011d208 0x10011d324 0x187d91f38 0x187e50018 0x187f0cb70 0x187f1a030 0x187c4dc24 0x182f20588 0x182f1e32c 0x182f1e75c 0x182e4d680 0x18435c088 0x187cc4d90
0x1001650d8 0x1829ee8b8)

Comment: Had you set the identifier name in the segue in storyboard?

Comment: Yes I set it different than the one on the code .

Comment: Yes, this is what I did !

Comment: Did you drag the connection from View? or from the button itself? You should actually drag from View

Comment: If you drag the segue directly from button, it will directly go to the view ignoring identifier, BUT if you drag from segue then you can programatically perform where to go according to identifier. Make sure your identifier are the same name, because this error might come from cant find a segue of that identifier

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working Now. Thanks,,,